# Angular-material 5: Can't bind to 'disableOptionCentering' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Getting this error while trying to add the [disableOptionCentering]="true" on the dropdown: Can't bind to 'disableOptionCentering' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-select'

Current Version: Angular and material both 5

Problem statement: Trying to solve the issue of the dropdown being overlapped on the label. I already tried it on the plunker and it works, I want to know what version of angular material am supposed to use.

Working example: https://angular-veauye.stackblitz.io

What version of material or angular I need to use for this to work or am I missing some other import in modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the Angular material version above 6,

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.3",
    "@angular/common": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/core": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/forms": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/http": "6.0.9",
    "@angular/material": "^6.3.3"
}
```